# How to check if data exsists in the database so you can update it

Tags: laravel-5

This code above adds data to the database but it does not update if the data already exsists.

```
     public function updateStudentPastoral(){

   // Getting all post data
    $data = Input::all();


        $pCollection = new PastoralCollection();
        $pCollection->fill($data);
        $response = '';
        if ($pCollection->save())
            $response = 'success';
        else
            $response = 'error';

        return (json_encode($response));
 }
```

i want to check if the data already exists so i will update it in the database but if it does exist it will save in the database.

Comment: You have to specify what you mean by exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel firstOrnew method like so:

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => Input::get('name')));
$user->foo = Input::get('foo');
$user->save();
```

This will check if there is a record matching name if there is it will be updated otherwise a new one will be createad.